# Getting trouble in changing the parameter value which i got in the response of HTTP request while recording

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded steps through BadBoy tool and exported those to JMeter- one parameter value as a HTTP response (OrderID) got recorder in one of the step. 
Now when i run same steps for performance testing with thread group in JMeter it is passing that constant orderId every-time which was got recorder while recording the steps but what i need is Jmeter should capture the real time orderid's which would be the response of HTTP requests and those should be unique.

Note: Currently it is passing that constant orderid which i got while recording the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the usage of **Regular Expression Extractor**  that you can find in JMeter (Add > Post Processor).

Once you understand it, you can use it to extract the OrderID value from your responses and store them in a variable.

After that you can use this variable where ever required.

Please refer to following link for reading more on JMeter Reg Expression Extractors.

[tutorial for Reg Expression Extractor](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/stress-testing-dynamic-pages-using-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter won't handle dynamic values automatically, unlike LoadRunner it doesn't have autocorrelation feature so you will have to deal with this OrderID (and maybe others) manually. The process in general looks as follows:

- HTTP Request (which returns OrderID)

  - PostProcessor (to extract OrderID and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html))
- HTTP Request (which sends JMeter Variable having dynamic OrderID value)

Where **PostProcessor** can be

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - for text
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) - for HTML
- [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) - for XML, XHTML and HTML
- [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) - for JSON

You may also find useful [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination, they allow to inspect JMeter Variables and Properties names and values as well as request and response details.